# Can I make an XCTest Expectation without failing?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am using Xcode 7,  Swift UI Automation. I need to wait for a UIButton to appear in my home screen. I set an expectation for "exists == 1".

This UIButton sometimes appears, sometime it doesn't.
During my UI test, if the element appears, everything is OK.
But if the element does not appear, the expectation fails (and I don't want it to fail, I just need to take another flow of action)

How can I make a decision withour the test actually failing?

Comment: If you know about when the button should show up, you could just add in a short sleep call `sleep(3)`, and then check if the button is there

Comment: That is what i a doing, and exactly what i want to avoid. I don't want to use sleep() calls. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to wait for the expectation and handle it if this doesn't happens do something else into the brackets.

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: UIButton, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10) { error in

   somethings else
}
```

Cheers